# How do I animate pseudo elements like :before on webkit browsers?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS3 transitions on pseudo-elements (:after, :before) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578424/css3-transitions-on-pseudo-elements-after-before-not-working)

My CSS transitions only work in Firefox...not sure why it is not animating in chrome, safari, or Opera.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/HUDuy/

HTML:

```
<ol class="steps">
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Baz</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol.steps {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: step-counter;
  padding-left: 60px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol.steps li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 50px;
}

ol.steps li:before {
  content: counter(step-counter, decimal);
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #aaa;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

ol.steps li:hover:before {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  left: -57px;
  top: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: i updated the code for brevity.

Comment: is there a polyfill or work around?

Comment: How else do you use counters w/o psuedo elements? It specifically rquires content: my-counter(li)

Comment: i'll just wait for the inferior browsers to catchup to firefox ;)

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10578718/295264):

WebKit (Chrome, Safari) does not support transitions on pseudo elements.

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23209
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54699

Firefox does indeed.

Comment: That is no longer the case (2019 Jan). Chrome supports them, but so far I was not able to get them to work on Safari.