# CSS - Pseudo classes :before and :after transitions

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create hover transition effect for pseudo classes `:before` and `:after`. I'm unable to achieve the result I'm hoping for.

[Please have a look at this example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/tkhg2myl).

It all seems logical to me, but I'm pretty sure I'm missing a point. The transition just does not work.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578424/css3-transitions-on-pseudo-elements-after-before-not-working

Comment: what's wrong with the demo? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that not all browser supports this. Look at [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)

However, shouldn't be complicated to add an element inside your div to achieve the desired result.