# Put animation on pseudo-elements with content

Tags: html, css, transition

I have some minor problems with some CSS pseudo-elements.
I am trying to make my custom tooltip, fade in and out, when hovering, but it doesn't seems to work.

The pseudo-element, are getting the content from an `data-title` HTML5 tag.

---

I have tried this, without any luck:

```
span:before, span:after {
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s;
   -moz-transition: all .2s;
   -o-transition: all .2s;
   -ms-transition: all .2s;
   transition: all .2s;
}

span:hover:after {
   content: attr(data-title);
   display: block;
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFF;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   border-radius: 3px;
   left: -20px;
   top: 46px;
}
```

The tooltip shows properly, but without the transition. I have also tried to add a `content: ""` in the `span:before, span:after` section, without any luck either.

---

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDq9f/3/

Anyone who can help me please?

Comment: Might could helps. [CSS3 transitions on pseudo-elements (:after, :before) not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578424/css3-transitions-on-pseudo-elements-after-before-not-working)

Comment: When trying that, the buttons are moving up and down. But the animation works. http://jsfiddle.net/nDq9f/4/

Comment: Don't understood the _text in the buttons breaks at the white-spaces_. At the margins? Buttons also moving up and down when you hover?

Comment: Nothing happens to the text anyway. Now the only problems is, that the buttons are moving up and down, when hovering, and the text in the pseudo-element messes up when you are moving the cursor away from the button. You can see it at the fiddle in my first comment.

Comment: Let me now if my answer helps you

Comment: I got it fixed! I tried to move all the styling like display, width, height, background etc... from span:hover:after over in the span:after. http://jsfiddle.net/nDq9f/7/. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: Glad could help. Just answer your own question and accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got i fixed!

I but all the styling *(display, width, height etc...)* in the `span:before, span:after` part, instead of in the `:hover` part. Then it all worked perfect!

You can see the fiddle in the bottom of this post.

```
span:before, span:after {
   content: attr(data-title);
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFF;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   border-radius: 3px;
   left: -20px;
   top: 46px;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s;
   -moz-transition: all .2s;
   -o-transition: all .2s;
   -ms-transition: all .2s;
   transition: all .2s;
}

span:hover:after {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

I also added a `pointer-events: none;` so you can't make the tooltip appear when hovering it, when it has `opacity: 0;`

[Here's the js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDq9f/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this in your `span:before, span:after`:

```
span:before, span:after {
    content: attr(title);
    filter: alpha(opacity=00);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

**NOTE:** the `content: attr(title);` property makes all sense

Comment: You have some errors in your css, like as `border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0,0,0,0.75); transparent;`... And you doesn't only change my CSS. :P Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscocarvalho/nDq9f/6/).